# please make this javascript display toggle work with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, styles, toggle

Can someone please make this work with multiple classes. It currently only works with one and I dont know javascript

```
<!--
var toggle_visibility = (function(){
   function toggle(el){
      el.style.display = el.style.display==='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
   }
   return function(cl){
      var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
      for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i){
         toggle(els[i]);
      }
   };
})();
//-->
```

Also heres a copy of how I am running the script

```
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('nyc');">New York</a></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('photoshop');">Photoshop Work</td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('photography');">Photography</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('art');">Art Projects</td></tr>
```

so i just want it to work like this

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('art','photoshop','photography');">New York</td>
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the rest of the elements, when one option is chosen/clicked?

Comment: yeah, so it jsut shows the selection

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this (If you wan't something else then let me know, your uestion is not clear)

```
$(function(){
    $('table#items').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr').not($(this).closest('tr')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Put the code in the `<head>` section between `<script>` like

```
<head>
    <script type="tetx/javascript">
        // code goes here
    </script>
</head>
```

Also, these `<!-- //-->` are unnecessary nowadays, we don't live in an ancient age of browsers (IMO)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/WfArK/).

Also note that your `HTML` is broken, check the `HTML` in the demo. Also, if you don't want to use an `id` (I've used `id='items'`) for the table then just use `$(table)` instead of `$(table#items)`.